# Specifikation of operation in VDM++

Tags: vdm++

I would like to know what the operations mean in the picture. Most what the line, 'getStartPrice()== (return startPrice)' mean.

I'm really new too this.

[image]

Comment: Do not put code as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The "getStartPrice() ==" line defines the action of the operation. What may be a surpise is that an operation (or function) definition starts with two lines. The first line defines the type signature, like "op: nat * nat ==> nat", and the second line names the parameters, like "op(a, b) == ...". The body of the operation can then follow after the "==", unless it is implicit.

Comment: Thank you very much. Help me a lot.